# Consuming Web Service in console C#

Tags: c#, web-services, console, console-application

I'm trying to consume a WebService in a console application, but I keep getting this error.

> 'Unable to load endpoint configuration section for
> 'Giftcard.WebServiceSoap' contract. Found more than one configuration
> for the contract. Indicate the preferred endpoint configuration
> section by name.'

This is my code:

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserWebService.WebServiceSoapClient webServiceSoapClient = new UserWebService.WebServiceSoapClient();
            string id = "12345543";
            webServiceSoapClient.Login(id);
        }
    }
```

WEB Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WebServiceSoap">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="WebServiceSoap1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="WebServiceSoap12">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpsTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://localhost:444/WebService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WebServiceSoap" contract="UserWebService.WebServiceSoap"
                name="WebServiceSoap" />
            <endpoint address="https://localhost:444/WebService.asmx" binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WebServiceSoap12" contract="UserWebService.WebServiceSoap"
                name="WebServiceSoap12" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I've added the reference to the webservice from here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using .net or net framework console app?

Comment: what in the config file for that section

Answer (score 0):

Add the bindingConfiguration="**WebServiceSoap**" name you want to use in the constructor of UserWebService.WebServiceSoapClient("WebServiceSoap").

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserWebService.WebServiceSoapClient webServiceSoapClient = new UserWebService.WebServiceSoapClient("WebServiceSoap");
            string id = "12345543";
            webServiceSoapClient.Login(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: 'WebServiceSoap' is a 'construct', which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: Please add double quote  for the name "WebServiceSoap"